# XML Parser for colon-separated tags?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

If I have colon separated xml tags like `<my:tag>`, which library provides easy parsing and value manipulation? What do I have to look for?

Comment: never understood your question!

Comment: could you post an example of your xml

Comment: Any reasonable XML parser should support namespaces.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the colon?  The colon is a delimiter between the namespace and the tag name.  Any XML parser should handle namespaces, but usually you will need to know the actual namespace name (and not the abbreviated name in the tag) to parse it (and the actual name is found somewhere in the XML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `my` before the colon is a *namespace prefix*, and there should be an attribute `xmlns:my` on either the same element or one of its enclosing elements somewhere higher up which associates a *namespace URI* with the prefix. All the standard Java XML technologies support namespaces (SAX, DOM and StAX provided with the JRE as well as third party libraries like JDOM and XOM), the thing you need to remember is that you generally refer to elements in any API using the namespace URI and local name (the bit after the colon), not the prefix specifically.

Comment: wonderful explanation.