# XML DOM: Selecting a node with namespace by name

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I read an XML that is signed and comes in the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><principal><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#1500-Fri Jan 30 19:11:38 BOT 2015"><ds:Transforms>s:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>YOzKDc7CB3QvedYMF2ZBB6omlsg=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>DLZKHySIMKwFuB1wc8cR7w/UbLhYyZtul/ndFch1GCeiKrmohyNOGO82Hbcm+rFEWxK1yMx2sKtMKnuPTTCnIiZaYCLax5UJUe27AVqzpHZOc7+UKBmQoOOi3gYfAuyCZX5xBv0lrFNuigoNv6b0Z00Bu5Eu5e2zf01zceUqig40Y3yWUpEVRl+nbEUmVEBT+8fFwcigIQhqMbwFftGO8mcu55VKbGmMZS7cpwzfq+PsTrnDDHbZ9cme/8p3lWo8TGTEDTcQ2HZoSI5VAPR2/fGDGKtS5PEG0Vbb0WFdVZ+PKuOAhXqiP947xi6PP6Qv1bCbUqwsNLwTfuTjNR9lGg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:KeyName>1500</ds:KeyName></ds:KeyInfo><ds:Object Id="1500-Fri Jan 30 19:11:38 BOT 2015"><SER><num>150049</num><cod>HJYafrtr3456ABDFG</cod><pais>BO</pais</SER></ds:Object></ds:Signature><Otro>Imagen</Otro></principal>
```

reading from java:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
NodeList signatures = 
    doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS ,"ds:Signature");
System.out.println("the length "+ signatures.getLength());
```

returns " signatures.getLength() " = 0, I tried with:

```
NodeList signatures = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS ,"ds");
NodeList signatures = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS ,"Signature");
```

as could read the tag `<ds:Signature>`.  How do I select this signature node?

Comment: Probably this is what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623505/xml-parser-for-colon-separated-tags
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785054/how-to-parse-an-xml-with-colons-in-some-tags

Comment: Your XML is malformed. I pasted it into the validator at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and there's syntax error. Nothing else is going to work without valid XML.

Comment: **<pais>BO</pais</SER>** - here a ">" is missing.

Comment: Has been verified xml I get this correctly assembled elque climbed to the example clearly shows errors, but has been corrected but I still can read the field "ds: Signature"

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the parser produced by this code will provide support for XML namespaces and use the proper url.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbFactory.setValidating(true);
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
String docNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
Element principal = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList signatures = principal.getElementsByTagNameNS(docNS ,"Signature");
System.out.println("the length "+ signatures.getLength());
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the XML input supplied was still not valid. I had to edit `ds:Transform` in order to get a valid document. It now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<principal>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#1500-Fri Jan 30 19:11:38 BOT 2015">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>YOzKDc7CB3QvedYMF2ZBB6omlsg=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>DLZKHySIMKwFuB1wc8cR7w/UbLhYyZtul/ndFch1GCeiKrmohyNOGO82Hbcm+rFEWxK1yMx2sKtMKnuPTTCnIiZaYCLax5UJUe27AVqzpHZOc7+UKBmQoOOi3gYfAuyCZX5xBv0lrFNuigoNv6b0Z00Bu5Eu5e2zf01zceUqig40Y3yWUpEVRl+nbEUmVEBT+8fFwcigIQhqMbwFftGO8mcu55VKbGmMZS7cpwzfq+PsTrnDDHbZ9cme/8p3lWo8TGTEDTcQ2HZoSI5VAPR2/fGDGKtS5PEG0Vbb0WFdVZ+PKuOAhXqiP947xi6PP6Qv1bCbUqwsNLwTfuTjNR9lGg==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:KeyName>1500</ds:KeyName>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:Object Id="1500-Fri Jan 30 19:11:38 BOT 2015">
      <SER>
        <num>150049</num>
        <cod>HJYafrtr3456ABDFG</cod>
        <pais>BO</pais>
      </SER>
    </ds:Object>
  </ds:Signature>
  <Otro>Imagen</Otro>
</principal>
```

The following code seems to solve the issue you're having.

```
public static void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File("YourFile.xml");

        if (file.exists() == true)
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = db.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList signatures = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
            System.out.print(signatures.getLength());

            Node signatureNode = signatures.item(0);
            NodeList childNodes = signatureNode.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++)
            {
                System.out.print(childNodes.item(i));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //  Swallow exception
    } 
}
```

Note that all I've really changed is changed this:

```
NodeList signatures = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS ,"ds:Signature");
```

To this:

```
NodeList signatures = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
```

I hope this helps.